Isn't it useful to have a content Posting section and Filtered content searching?
Posting section
Isn't it useful to have a personal posting section for personal opinions, experience, (something similar to social media)?
Filtered content searching
Isn't it useful to have off stack content search service inside every stack site, filtered by the subject of every stack site?
Otherwise, sometimes, by the nature of not use of seeded questions, some stack sites lack very major points/information regarding a subject on a relevant stack sites.

Posting section
We (users and moderators of this site) can't change the built-in functionality of this web site -- e.g. its software, navigation tools, etc.
Therefore for example we can't create a different section.
You could post a feature-request on the SE network's main meta-site i.e. https://meta.stackexchange.com/ but I doubt that would be effective.
Without changing the site in theory we might try to use it differently, e.g. try to simulate a different section by defining a new tag like personal-opinion -- and agree collectively that posts using this are not subject to the usual Q&A format, and instead any and all personal opinion is on-topic -- however:

It's not evident how to moderate that

It's not what the site is for, which is as stated on the Tour page:




It's so contrary to what's normal that I doubt whether I should go along with it, as moderator -- part of my role here is to help people use the site as it's described in all the various Help topic, including the Code of Conduct:





A lot of what you're asking for is why there is a "chat" section:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism
https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat

But people of this site tend not to use the "chat" room, for whatever reason.
Filtered content searching
Again we can't implement new software e.g. "a search feature".
Maybe you'd like the Community Wiki.
It's an old idea, introduced in 2011 and maybe deprecated later -- but some topics might perhaps do well with a Community Wiki page?
Here's an example of one:

Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts

That's maybe an example of a "search"-related topic.
